# PyQGIS importing CSV changes projection of basemap

Tags: qgis, python

I am using PyQGIS to import a csv file with a lat and long, when doing this I am using the appropriate crs of EPSG:4326. I'm plotting this onto Google Maps.

I load my basemap, then import my CSV. The issue is that my basemap projection then changes to 4326 and I need it to remain on 3857.

I've tried importing the basemap after the CSV and moving it down in the layers, however this still changes the projections.

```
import requests
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from qgis.core import * 
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis import core 

#Use Google Street Map as QGIS basemap. 

service_url = "mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
service_uri = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=21&url=https://"+requests.utils.quote(service_url) 
tms_layer = iface.addRasterLayer(service_uri, "GoogleSat", "wms") 

#Import CSV and plot. 
uri = 'file:///home/user/fred.csv?type=csv&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s' % ("Site Longitude", "Site Latitude", "EPSG:4326") 
layer_csv = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'fred', 'delimitedtext') 
layer_csv.isValid() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer_csv
```

I'll be the first to admit I'm a novice with QGIS.